# iOS standard buttons? UIButton vs. UIBarButtonItem vs. my own design?

Tags: ios, uibutton, icons, uibarbuttonitem

So I want to use iOS standard button icons for my buttons. I also need to tint them programmatically.

So far I found out:

1. Information icon: I can do this with a `UIButton`, but not with a `UIBarButtonItem`.
2. Bookmarks icon: I can do this with a `UIBarButtonItem`, but not with a `UIButton`.
3. Settings icon: I can do this with neither of the above. I’ll have to provide my own design.

With my own design, I will be unable to use the tint property, so I’ll actually have to provide it in different colors.

Is this correct?

Is there any reason why Apple is so picky about what system icons we’re allowed to use? Should’t great UI design rely on standards / predicted behavior?

Comment: I just found out that tinting my own design UIBarButtonItem works. This is cool! However, I’m still puzzled why we should be allowed to use only some, but not all icons.

Comment: Read the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/). Don't skim, because your questions are answered in there, and it'll save you a lot of headache down the road.

Comment: who voted to close this valid question???

Answer (score -2):

You need to design your own icons. You must NOT use Apple's icon in your app ever. They are copyrighted by Apple. If you use any of their icon, your app will be rejected by Apple App Reviewer when you submit your app to App Store.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? Why would they make the default icons so easy to use thene?